# Passport Authentication in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, express, passport.js

Below is the Code that i'm working on but i'm getting errors while executing.
Please help me in creating routes for both login and register forms which are on the same page.
When I'm submitting the registration form with this code, I'm getting an error which says "Bad request"

```
var express = require ('express');
var app = express();
var path= require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport();
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
var User = require('./models/user');


app.set('port',  process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(require('express-session')({
  secret: 'Working on enroll Medicare',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/registration");
app.post('/login-register.html', function(req,res)
{
            var username = req.body.usernameregister;
            var email = req.body.emailregister;
            var password1 = req.body.password1register;
            var password2 = req.body.password2register;
        password1, password2: password2}
        User.register(new User({username: username, email: email}), password1, function(err, user){
          if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return res.render('error');
          }
          passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function(){
              res.redirect("/secret");
          });
        });
});
```

login page

```
 app.post("/login-register.html", passport.authenticate('local', {
  succesRedirect: "/secret",
   failureRedirect: "/error"
 }), function(req, res){ });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have multiple problems here. Here are a few things to check:

- You have `passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));`. I don't know what `User.authenticate()` returns, but it should return a function with the arguments `function(username, password, done) {...}`
- It looks like you're using `email` as the username. You need to add `usernameField` to the strategy options: `new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'email'}, function(email, password, done){...})`
- I've also found it really helpful to use a custom callback in the `passport.authenticate` function to see if the returned error provides any more information about the problem: `passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {console.log(err, user, info)})`